# can't connect to my sql DB server

Tags: azure, azure-sql

I'm trying to connect to my sql DB in azure with my primary username and password (I don't have any other username and password) and its failed. I'm 100% sure I entered the right username and password.

is there anything I can do to connect my DB?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the admin password in the portal(or via CLI)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/07/23/reset-lost-admin-account-password/

```
1   Using Azure Portal open your Azure SQL Server blade (do not confuse with the database blade)
2   Make sure you are in the Overview blade.
3   Click on "Reset password" at the top of the overview blade.
4   Set the new password and click save.
```